# WPF media player listbox as a playlist

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, media

I'm making a media player in WPF. I was thinking to use listbox control for playlist.

I have no idea how to bind clicking on an item of listbox and playing that item, and also making my player do shuffle or repeat for these items.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224435/playlist-for-wpf-mediaelement-app) doesn't solve my problem

Comment: How does your internal song structure look at the moment? See my answer for a suggestion if it's something `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

To start, you could set the `ItemSource` of your `ListBox` to an internal `IEnumerable` structure, for instance a `SongList = List<Song>` containing references to your songs. Then attach a `DoubleClick` event handler to your `ListBox`. On a double click event, `sender` should now be  your `ListBox`. The selected item (song) should then be `(sender as EventList).SelectedItems[0]`. See if this item is in your `SongList`, and if it is, play it!

Your XAML code could look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="songList" MouseDoubleClick="songList_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=songName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And in your initialization code:

```
songList.ItemSource = InternalSongList;
```

And event handler:

```
private void songList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Controls.ListBox songList = sender as Controls.ListBox;
    if (songList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Song selectedSong = songList.SelectedItems[0];

        // To be on the safe side
        if (InternalSongList.Contains(selectedSong))
        {
            selectedSong.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This could of course be improved with security, and I suppose the playing of the song is a bit more complicated in reality. As for shuffle, a random function selecting an index for your internal list should probably do it. Repeat should be equally simple: count the songs played and make sure no song is played twice. When all songs have been played once, clear your list of played songs and repeat! The advantage of using an `IEnumerable` is that you don't need to touch the `ListBox` that much, just set the `ItemsSource` and it handles itself pretty well.

Comment: Is it possible that my ListBox is a list of songs, not creating IEnumerable?

Comment: Yes, because `List` implements `IEnumerable`. You could in this case see the `IEnumerable` interface as a condition: any container that is to be used as an `ItemSource` for a `ListBox` needs to implement `IEnumerable`. `List` and many other C# containers implement this interface.